# Design time width/height of Image control in wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am creating an image gallery control in WPF, and try to use as much designtime data as possible  to ease the tweaking from within Visual Studio (2013).

So far I have the following code, that works as intented at runtime, but the designer seems to be ignoring d:DesignHeight and d:DesignWidth attribut on the Image element.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ImageGalleryControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="400"
             d:DesignWidth="800"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=DesignData/ImageCollection.xaml}">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}"
                           d:DesignHeight="150"
                           d:DesignWidth="150"
                           Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=ImageWidth}"
                           Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=ImageWidth}"
                           Margin="3"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

It picks up the designtime data as expected from the ImageCollection.xaml, but not the design height on the Image element. Is it not supposed to work that way, my google fu fails me, or is there another way I can achieve the same?

Comment: Perhaps you could try putting your d:DesignHeight **after** your Height declarations?

Comment: Doesn't work and I would be extremely surprised if it did.

Comment: I am not sure it's meant to be used for anything but the root element, but it's valid XAML, and I cannot find any documentation on it.

I know why the binding cannot resolve at designtime, hence I want to use designheight/width. It's the simplest way I can figure out to keep the size purely in the UI where it belongs, and the purpose (user can select the prefered size of the images, and it will make the image close to said size to evenly fill out the availble space) it works very well.

Comment: I ended up seting  MinHeight="42", MinWidth="180"
        Height="{Binding Win_Height, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Width="{Binding Win_Width, Mode=TwoWay}"
to kind of get around this